# Compositor ID Mask not working?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-passes, id-mask

I want to give my model a glare effect at robots *eye*,

[image]

so I gave the material *assigned to the eye* Pass Index of 1

[image]

then when I went to compositor and made this node set up,

[image]

in the viewer I could not see anything like that, (BW Image)

[image]

Comment: could you upload the blendfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty weird. I can think of three possible workarouds:

- Render the eye as a separate object, then use Object Index.
- Render the eye on a separate RenderLayer.
- As the eye seems to be pretty much an emission material, you could separate the emission pass.

Answer (score 6):

Your setup seems to be correct.

The material you want to use as mask must have an Pass Index number.

[image]

In the render layers enable Material Index

[image]

Now press **<kbd>F12</kbd>**: **YOU HAVE TO RENDER THE IMAGE** for this changes to update, and the compositor has the proper information to work with (Sounds simple, but this step is sometimes overlooked).

After that, the node setup could be something like this, where the ID mask index matches the index set for the eye material and is used as a mask for further transformations:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to reconnect the Image ID slot to the ID Mask. You connected from the all first node to the Id Mask node. Try pulling of this connection and then putting it in again. Just unconnect and then connecting the Id slot of the Render Layers node (IndexMA) anew to the ID Mask (ID value).

I think this solved this issue for me. I reconnected after I had changed the index number inside the mask or the index number of the material itself.