# How to simulate overexposure due to bright light? (Cycles)

Tags: modeling, rendering, node-editor, workflow, light

I try to make a animation where the light of my object gets brighter until the picture is white.
*I only want that the intensity of the light rises*, so that it looks like the light shines directly in the camera. Then the other objects in the picture should fade to white from the lightsource.
Unfortunately I didn't find a video to show you what I want.

I had a few ideas how I can accomplish that, but none of them worked.

1.I tried to increase the gamma of the picture.
But then the whole picture getting brighter at the same time, and thats not what I want. I want that *it spreads from* the lightsource.

[image]

2. I tried it with volume scattering, but there I have the same effect because I have multiple lights and all are effected by the scattering

EDIT:

3. I tried to do it with glare but that effects the whole image too.
4. With compositing and glare I get the glow I want. But I am not able to increase it so far that the screen gets white.

[image]

So how can I get the effect I want?

And even if its not good to ask two questions (but it belongs to my first question)
Do I have to render my animation again after the composing?

Here is a file if you want to look: [image]

Comment: This is generally achieved with filters in post production, not directly in the 3D scene. See the if the [*Glow* filter in the compositor](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/how-to-make-edge-glow) achieves what you want.

Comment: Yes that looks really good! But can I animate this ? That the glow is getting brighter and spreads out from the source?

Comment: Glow effect in the compositor will react to the image lighting changes so animating the material would do. For additional effect you may also animate the effect in the compositor without increasing rendering time

Comment: Yes I saw this, but it didn't solve my problem (if I understood you right). But with my answer below it works halfways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I found a solution, for now.
It doesn't look realistc but better than nothing.
With this nodesetup its possible to increase the brightness to white and then spreading out from the source.

If you increase the value of the multiply-node the light is getting brighter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the contrast of the render doesn't work for you?
[image]

Comment: Thank you,but I also tried this. There I have the same problem. As you can see in your picture, the color at the borders are changing from the beginning. And I want that the light spreads out from the source. I'll try to make a video to make it more clear what I mean.

Comment: I get what you mean now, so maybe apply some mask to change the brightness only in the area of the shiny material (if the camera is not moving) or animate material's glossiness?

Comment: So I have to edit every singe frame ? Or can I make that automatically? How should I do this and can I do it with blender, or do I have to use another programm?

Comment: Do you use Cycles or Blender Internal rendering engine? If Cycles, this post could be useful for you http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35448/13643

Comment: So then I have to make another object as a mask where I increase the contrast? But is it then possible to get a radial gradient on it ? That the contrast at the mid is higher than at the outside?

Comment: I am sure you can assign the mask for the material, not an object.